# How can I solve this circuit with two BJTs?

Tags: bjt

[image]

I am analyzing the circuit in the picture attached. It's a connection with two BJTs biased slightly different, both having the same load.

The struggle I have here is that any method of calculation I try, I do not get a real answer.

First, I am assuming Vbe = 0.65 ,which then gives me a result that does not match the current going through R3 and splitting between the base current and R4.

What I can observe is that there is less available voltage for biasing Q2 then biasing Q1, meaning that the base current and the Vbe will be lower for Q2.

From simulation, Vbe for Q2 is close to 0.5V and it's operating in linear mode.

What I'm trying to get here is to see a different approach into solving the circuit by calculation. I know that trying to get the real Vbe is an iterative approach, but I'm interested in calculating the base currents for Q2 and Q1.

Comment: You must show us your calculation steps, otherwise we are not able to tell you where you fail.

Comment: How can you "measure" Ib's? Q2 is off, Q1 is fully on...

Comment: @StefanWyss I can add the calculations but the main idea is that I want to see a different approach, not something linked to what I did. I am trying to get a better idea on how to perform analysis on BJT circuits and learn from the more experienced. 
Shortly what I did is that I wrote Kirchhoff's laws for voltages and currents and tried to solve the system.

Comment: @Antonio51 I did not mention anything about measuring. Also, Q2 is not off, there is a collector current flowing.

Comment: Base current for Q2 won't be very interesting because it's running at very low current.  Are you familiar with the Ebers-Moll model?

Comment: ib(q1)=136 uA (-> ON, Vce=48 mV) and ib(q2)=45 nA (-> OFF, Vce=4.97 V).

Comment: Mark base of Q2 as V2, base of Q1 as V3 and midpoint of R1, R2, and R3 as V1. Then three equations: `V1/R3+V1/R2+V1/R1=5/R1+V2/R3+V3/R2`, `V3/R2+Isat1*(exp(V3/VT)-1)=V1/R2`, and `V2/R3+V2/R4+Isat2*(exp(V2/VT)-1)=V1/R3`. You will need the LambertW function, a specific branch of it, to solve this with a closed equation for V1, V2, and V3.

Answer (score 2):

> I am doing an assumption of Vbe = 0.65

The Vbe's are almost certainly different, and assuming they are the same will almost certainly lead to contradictions.

Here is your circuit (with incorrect transistors).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIuP68.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Notice that R3 and R4 form an approximately 0.25 Voltage divider. This means that \$V_{B2}\$ is going to be about 0.25 or less of \$V_{A}\$. Since \$V_{B2}\$ is going to be small, \$I_{B2}\$ will likewise be small. Thus, we will temporarily treat \$I_{B2}\$ as negligible.

The circuit then reduces as follows.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNdpYa.png)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbTOYl.png)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2suUw.png)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOX1UE.png)</sup>

Now, with this transistor, (and this transistor only!) you can make an assumption about the Vbe being approximately 0.7 V. This gives a
Ib of approximately (3.8873-0.7)/23.822 = 134 uA. Since we do not know the actual parameters of the transistor, we will stop with the analysis of this transistor here. With assumptions about current gain, we could analyze this transistor further.

Turning now to Q2. We want to reduce this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl4PsT.png)</sup>

First we want to find the Thevenin equivalent to this circuit with node \$A\$ as output:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f80UAM.png)</sup>

When \$A\$ is open, we have have 134 uA flowing through a 17.8 \$k\Omega\$ resistor. giving a 2.385 V drop. The Thevenin equivalent voltage is then 5-2.385 = 2.615V. We then short \$A\$ to ground and find that 5/17.8 = 281 uA flows through R1. 134 uA of that flows through the current source, so only 147 uA flows from \$A\$ to ground. The Thevenin equivalent resistance is the Thevenin equivalent voltage divided by the short circuit current output current, or 2.615/134u = 19.5k. So we want to reduce the following circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fogs7v.png)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcxdba.png)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9AbYU.png)</sup>

Since the Thevenin voltage is only about 500 mV, our original assumption to treat \$I_{b2}\$ as negligible in our first analysis is justified. Again, the Ic for this transistor depends upon the transistor parameters, and we will not calculate a value here.

Comment: In addition to the mentioned three parameters (VA, VBE1, VBE2) the faktor k (Current Io)  - a very temperature-sensitive value - must also be assumed.  A lot of assumptions which make the whole analysis pretty questionable.

Comment: This looks really promising. Could you please explain how you simplified to the last part? I cannot get the 508mV Thevenin voltage and the 11.6Ω (which if I'm not wrong should be kΩ). Thanks!

Comment: @Lowrdson I edited my answer to show my work. I came up with 497 mV, this time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as follows:
During simulation fixed BJT parameters (contained in the used models) are assumed.

The shown circuit has no negative feedback - and as a consequence, the DC operating point strongly depends on these unknown transistor parameters (Vbe, B resp h21).

Such BJT-based circuits can be (roughly) manually analyzed only when there is enough negative feeback which makes the DC operating point less sensible against these unknown parameters.

As a consequence, it makes not much sense to assume some arbitrary values for Vbe and/or B.

Answer (score 1):

Analysis by inspection of the circuit:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I am trying now to follow and solve myself using the same method. The only question I have is how Ic2 can be 43mA if the load resistor is 5kΩ supplied from 5V? I think that shows that Q2 is saturated and during saturation, the Beta value does not hold anymore.

Comment: Yes, something is wrong. I'm checking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's start with your assumption of Vbe=0.65V. Calculate Rx = R2||R3 = 8.23kOhm. Now calculate the voltage on the middle node: Vx = Rx/(Rx+R1)*(5V-0.65V)+0.65V = 2.03V. Iq1 = (2.03-0.65)/R2 = 138uA.

I leave the rest to you.